# Contingency table counting by date and by parameter

Tags: r, count

I have a dataframe where in each row there is, among other things, a date and a parameter. I need to create a table where I can see the number of occurrences day by day by parameter.

I can use `table(df$date, df$param)`, but the result is a three column table date-parameter-count.

I need a table like this:

```
DATE    | PARAM1    | PARAM2    | PARAM3    | ...
day1    | *count*   | *count*   | *count*   | ...
day2    | *count*   | *count*   | *count*   | ...
day3    | *count*   | *count*   | *count*   | ...
...     | ...       | ...       | ...       | ...
```

How can I get this table?

Comment: @RuiBarradas I made the example ... I am not sure how can I make it clearer than that. It's after "I need a table like this:"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, try this.
First, an example dataset.

```
set.seed(7811)    # make the results reproducible

DATE <- sample(as.Date("2017-01-01") + 0:9, 20, TRUE)
PARAM <- sample(c("PARAM1", "PARAM2", "PARAM3"), 20, TRUE)
df <- data.frame(DATE, PARAM)
df
```

Now the code.

```
library(reshape2)

dcast(df, DATE ~ PARAM)
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed. However I don't understand how such a common thing is not in the basic table function. I mean, it's the equivalent of a pivot table in excel